# Improving Collections.Sort

Tags: java

I am sorting 1 million strings (each string 50 chars) in ArrayList with

```
final Comparator comparator= new Comparator<String>() {

     public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

    if (s2 == null || s1 == null)
         return 0;
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
     }
};

Collections.Sort(list,comparator);
```

The average time for this is: 1300 millisec

How can I speed it up?

Comment: Implement the quick sort and use it on the list.

Comment: Why not use a `SortedSet`? Unless you have duplicates?

Comment: Not sure it has an impact on speed, but your comparator is incorrect: if you have s1 == null, s3 == "a" and s4 =="b", you'll have s1 == s3, s1 == s4, but s3 != s4. Decide if nulls come before or after non-nulls, but don't make two strings equal if one of them is null.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Java 6 or below you might get a speedup by switching to Java 7. In Java 7 they changed the sort algorithm to TimSort which performs better in some cases (in particular, it [works well with partially sorted input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)). Java 6 and below [used MergeSort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

---

But let's assume you're using Java 6. I tried three versions:

**Collections.sort()**: Repeated runs of the comparator you provided take about **3.0 seconds** on my machine (including reading the input of 1,000,000 randomly generated lowercase ascii strings).

**Radix Sort:** Other answers suggested a [Radix sort](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960123.html). I tried the following code (which assumes the strings are all the same length, and only lowercase ascii):

```
String [] A = list.toArray(new String[0]);

for(int i = stringLength - 1; i >=0; i--) {
  int[] buckets = new int[26];
  int[] starts = new int[26];
  for (int k = 0 ; k < A.length;k++) {
    buckets[A[k].charAt(i) - 'a']++;
  }
  for(int k = 1; k < buckets.length;k++) {
    starts[k] = buckets[k -1] + starts[k-1];
  }
  String [] temp = new String[A.length];
  for(int k = 0; k < A.length; k++) {
    temp[starts[A[k].charAt(i) - 'a']] = A[k];
    starts[A[k].charAt(i) - 'a']++;
  }    
  A = temp;
}
```

It takes about **29.0 seconds to complete** on my machine. I don't think this is the best way to implement radix sort for this problem - for example, if you did a most-significant digit sort then you could terminate early on unique prefixes. And there'd also be some benefit in using an in-place sort instead (There's a good quote about this - [“The troubles with radix sort are in
implementation, not in conception”](http://erik.gorset.no/2011/04/radix-sort-is-faster-than-quicksort.html)). I'd like to write a better radix sort based solution that does this - if I get time I'll update my answer.

**Bucket Sort:** I also implemented a slightly modified version of Peter Lawrey's [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) solution. Here's the code:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> buckets = new TreeMap<Integer,List<String>>();
for(String s : l) {
  int key = s.charAt(0) * 256 + s.charAt(1);
  List<String> list = buckets.get(key);
  if(list == null) buckets.put(key, list = new ArrayList<String>());
  list.add(s);
}
l.clear();
for(List<String> list: buckets.values()) {
    Collections.sort(list);
    l.addAll(list);
}
```

It takes about **2.5 seconds** to complete on my machine. I believe this win comes from the partitioning.

---

So, if switching to Java 7's TimSort doesn't help you, then I'd recommend partitioning the data (using something like [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)). If you need even better performance, then you can also multi-thread the processing of the partitions.

Comment: It should be faster to use HashMap and sort the result.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the sort algorithm you use some are quicker than others(quick/merge vs. bubble)
Also If you are running on a multi-core/multi-processor machine you can divide the sort between multiple thread (again exactly how depends on the sort algorithm but [here's](http://pguides.net/java/concurrency-sorting) an example)

Comment: He did specify that he's using Collections.sort, which uses a modified merge-sort. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29

Answer (score 2):

You can use a radix sort for the first two characters. If you first two characters are distinctive you can use something like.

```
List<String> strings = 
Map<Integer, List<String>> radixSort = 
for(String s: strings) {
  int key = (s.charAt(0) << 16) + s.charAt(1);
  List<String> list = radixSort.get(key);
  if(list == null) radixSort.put(key, list = new ArrayList<String>());
  list.add(s);
}
strings.clear();
for(List<String> list: new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>(radixSort).values()) {
    Collections.sort(list);
    strings.addAll(list);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually radix sort: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960123.html

Comment: I call it a partial radix sort, it breaks the data in to smaller subsets so you get closer the O(n) sort that a full radix sort provides. The worst case is no better however e.g. if every strings starts `aa`

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, what guaranties that iterration over the hashmap (retrievingthe lists) will load them in correct order? 
hash of integers?

Comment: -1: This is bucket sort, not radix sort (and you need to specify a Map  that sorts on the keys). But most importantly, the key calculation incorrectly sorts the data.

Comment: It will sort `aoa` before `aaa`

Comment: The keys need to be sorted first before merging.

Comment: Also you'll need to change `s.charAt(0) << 16 + s.charAt(1)` for `(s.charAt(0) << 16) + s.charAt(1)`, or more readably `s.charAt(0) * 65536 + s.charAt(1)`